# I am making a line following robot with obstacle detection

Tags: python, robotics

so I have made a code where it detects an obstacle it brakes elif it runs the trackok.py code

the problem is when it starts the trackok.py code it stays in it and doesn't stop even if an obstacle is in front of it.

this is the piece of code that has this algorithm

```
try:
    init()
    
    while True:
        GPIO.output(TrigPin, GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(0.00001)
        GPIO.output(TrigPin, GPIO.LOW)
        while GPIO.input(EchoPin)==0:
            pulse_start_time = time.time()
            GPIO.output(TrigPin,1)
            time.sleep(0.00001)
            GPIO.output(TrigPin,0)
        while GPIO.input(EchoPin)==1:
            pulse_end_time = time.time()
            pulse_duration = pulse_end_time - pulse_start_time
            distance = round(pulse_duration * 17150, 2)
            if distance > 5:
                os.system("python /home/pi/trackok.py")  
            elif distance < 5:
                brake()   
    
       
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
pwm_ENA.stop()
pwm_ENB.stop()
GPIO.cleanup()
```

for the full code and the trackok.py code, I will leave a link in here
[trackok.py](https://pastebin.pl/view/db954bdb)
[Full code](https://pastebin.pl/view/34c90740)

edit1:
Now I am sure the problem is in the trackok.py
I did this code and it keeps on printing the distance until it gets to the distance where it should start the trackok.py code it then runs that code and keeps looping in it without calculating any new distances here is the code
[new code](https://pastebin.pl/view/d55fc7d0)

edit2:
Ok so I combined both codes in 1 algorithm and I get this error now
the same thing happens tracking the line is working but ultrasonic runs for until tracking is on and then no more distance reading
here is the code [newest code](https://pastebin.pl/view/988d44b4)
the thing is I get this error now

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Trackerultrasonic.py", line 49, in <module>
    pwm_ENA = GPIO.PWM(ENA, 2000)
RuntimeError: A PWM object already exists for this GPIO channel
```

edit3:
This is the nearest I have reached now it runs the tracker and should light the blue led and brake() when it detects an obstacle
the issue is it detects the obstacle and the blue led lights up but doesn't brake() and it continues on the track
here is the newest code I have reached
[newest code](https://pastebin.pl/view/b00bf38f)

Comment: Have you tried any debugging or checked the sensor does what you expect?  I cannot see any print statements to help check flow in the code... Have you checked the OS call actually works or returns an error?

Comment: Yes the os call works i have tried it with a while true statement to make sure it works and tried the ultrasonic with a forward() and brake() and itr works 
so every code works alone but combined no 
my thaughts is that it loops inside the trakok.py and doesnt check anymore for the ultrasonic once it enters the tracker.py

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided is highly unlikely to work. The script trackok.py is going to be executed thousands of times in the loop, and each execution takes a huge time compared to how long the loop takes to execute each cycle. It is highly likely that by the time the script starts to run the distance will be less than 5, and by the time it has completed the robot will be well within or past its braking distance.

Comment: So what would you recommend me to do ?

Comment: I’d recommend you write all your code in a single Python program. Secondly, I’d suggest  you read Derek Molloy’s Exploring Raspberry Pi. It’s a a real in depth text, compared to most which are really too simple. Most small Python scripts will work fine,  but as they grow in size timing issues will arise if they are poling the GPIO pins for changes in input or trying to react quickly enough to events. 

Best of luck